# Laravel pagination add get parameters

Tags: php, laravel-5

When I use form I have that URL

```
view-source:http://teory.loc/realty/appartment_rent/day?city=&district=&cost_up=29999&cost_to=333333&rooms_up=&rooms_to=&area_up=&area_to=&floor_up=&floor_to=
```

for example

To handle this URL I used that code

```
 public static function search($paginate, $condotions = null, $order = null){



    return AppartmentRentDay::where(function ($query) use ($condotions){
        foreach ($condotions as $key => $value){
            if($value){
                $parametrs = [];
                if(substr($key,-3) == "_up"){
                    $parametrs[0] = substr($key,0,-3);
                    $parametrs[1] = '>=';
                }elseif (substr($key,-3) == "_to"){
                    $parametrs[1] = '<=';
                    $parametrs[0] = substr($key,0,-3);
                }else{
                    $parametrs[0] = $key;
                    $parametrs[1] = '=';
                }
                $query->where($parametrs[0], $parametrs[1], $value);
            }
        }
    })->paginate($paginate);

}
```

Paginate works right, but `{{ $info->links() }}` what gives for that hrefs

```
<ul class="pagination">
           <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
           <li class="active"><span>1</span></li>                                                                                
           <li><a href="http://teory.loc/realty/appartment_rent/day?page=2">2</a></li>
           <li><a href="http://teory.loc/realty/appartment_rent/day?page=2" rel="next">&raquo;</a></li>
        </ul>
```

And that works incorrect, how to add my get parameters for this href?

Plz give me some info
Ty
Laravel 5.5

Comment: Please include the url in the post itself as text.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can append the existing parameters to the links like this:

```
AppartmentRentDay::where(...)->paginate($paginate)->appends(request()->except('page'));
```

Comment: thank you very much, that works, if you can give me some url when i can read about that

Comment: The [documentation is a great place to start](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination#displaying-pagination-results). Scroll down to the section titled "Appending To Pagination Links"